# How can I make the javascript map, reduce syntax shorter and more readable?

Tags: javascript

How can I make the javascript map, reduce syntax shorter and more readable?

```
         const short = itemList.map(item => {
             end.id = item.id;
             end.floorName = Number(item.floor.id);
             item.findPath = FindByPoi(start, end);
             return item;
         }).reduce( (min, cur) => {
             const a = Math.min(min.findPath.distanceM, cur.findPath.distanceM);
             if(a === min.findPath.distanceM){
                 return min;
             }else if( a === cur.findPath.distanceM){
                 return cur;
             }
         });`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing what the code does, this is the best suggestion I can make that appears to be functionally equivalent to the code in question:

```js
const short = itemList.reduce((min, item) => {
  end.id = item.id;
  end.floorName = +item.floor.id;
  item.findPath = FindByPoi(start, end);
  return !(min.findPath.distanceM <= item.findPath.distanceM) ? item : min;
}, { findPath: { distanceM: NaN } });
```

Note that `!(min.findPath.distanceM <= item.findPath.distanceM)` is *not* equivalent to `item.findPath.distanceM < min.findPath.distanceM`, because the latter expression will evaluate to `false` if either value is `NaN`.

Comment: Why not use Infinity and simplify the ternary?

Comment: @DaveMeehan Because I don't know whether any of the items in the array can be expected to have a `distanceM` of `Infinity`. That's one of the many reasons my answer starts with the stipulation "Without knowing what the code does"...